# Copying files from text list

Tags: linux, perl, unix

I have a list of sample names in text format e.g.

```
Sample1
Sample2
etc....
```

Im trying to find and copy files with these names and a specific extension using the below one liner

```
 find ./ | egrep fq.gz | fgrep -f list.txt | perl -ne 'chomp; system "cp $_ /data/copy_of_files/"'
```

No errors are thrown up but nothing is copied.

This line works until I pass the output to perl (list of correct files prints in termial from the fgrep) so I think my issue is with the perl section...

any suggestions?

Comment: Just to clarify, You want to search for files with a certain extension (in this case .gz) then check if the contents of those file match one of the lines in list.txt, then copy them all to some directory?

Comment: No, if the name of the file contains one of the lines of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your original command and this command worked for me:

```
find . -name '*.gz' | fgrep -f list.txt | \
   perl -ne 'chomp; system("cp $_ <DIR>");'
```

Have you verified that your user or group have write permissions to `/data/copy_of_files`?

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:

1. Don't use Perl here, but instead, create a pipeline that just spits
   out the `cp` commands.  As soon as you're satisfied with what you
   see, append `| sh -x`.
2. Be absolutely sure that none of your file names contain whitespace or other characters special to the shell.  If some do, but only a little (e.g. only spaces), you may get by with appropriate quoting in the `cp` commands, but if anything is possible in filenames, a different approach will be required, and I would probably write the whole thing in Perl using [`File::Find::Rule`](http://search.cpan.org/~rclamp/File-Find-Rule-0.33/).